# Typescript and Javascript Array not showing length property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I have a complex interface that has properties that are arrays, it looks like this:

```
export interface Fundamentals {
BookValue: number;
EarningsQuarterly: EarningsQuarter[];
}
```

In my code , I load the interface from json like this

```
this.jsonData = JSON.parse(this.selectedSymbol.fundamentalJson);

this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly = <EarningsQuarter[]>this.jsonData.Earnings.History;
```

When I write the the console, I see that this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly has values.

However when I try to write

```
this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly.length
```

it shows as "undefined".

Also when I try

```
this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly.map(x => x.EpsEstimate)
```

I receive an error the map does not exist.

The console prints the this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly values in the console so I know it's loaded. See below

```
{
    "2023-06-30": {
        "ReportDate": "2023-07-26T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsEstimate": null,
        "EpsDifference": null,
        "SurprisePercent": null,
        "Date": "2023-06-30T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsActual": null
    },
    "2023-03-31": {
        "ReportDate": "2023-04-26T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsEstimate": null,
        "EpsDifference": null,
        "SurprisePercent": null,
        "Date": "2023-03-31T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsActual": null
    },
    "2022-12-31": {
        "ReportDate": "2023-02-09T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsEstimate": "-1.62",
        "EpsDifference": null,
        "SurprisePercent": null,
        "Date": "2022-12-31T00:00:00+00:00",
        "EpsActual": null
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` all the clues indicate that's not an array

Comment: ^ Could you log out the value of `this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly` and edit it into your question?

Comment: In the JavaScript world we say "if it walks like a duck, it quacks like a duck and it swims like a duck, then it's a duck". Your code is not quacking

Comment: Clearly, the JSON in `this.selectedSymbol.fundamentalJson` doesn't define an object with an `Earnings` property that has a `History` property that's an array. But without seeing the JSON, it's impossible to say what it is instead. You said it "has values," but haven't said what you're seeing that makes you think that. It *is* possible to define a non-array object that looks a bit like an array: `{"0": "zero", "1": "one"}`. But...

Comment: I added the output from the console. It shows the object loaded correctly

Comment: _"I added the output from the console."_ - which is clearly an object, and not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it's loaded. See below

> ```
> { 
>     "2023-06-30": {
> ```

So it's not an array, it's a key-value dictionary. If you want to get the equivalent of `length` of that, you can, for example, do `Object.values(this.fndFundamentals.EarningsQuarterly).length`

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed that. Super helpful!!!!!